# How to replace/rename the headers in a text file?

Tags: python, bash

I had around 10,000 text files in a directory,

1. I'd like to replace the **text file headers** with a **same keyword** (>zebra_cat).

**Orginal file**

```
head -n 1 dat.txt
>bghjallshkal
```

**Modified file**

```
head -n 1 dat.txt
>zebra_cat
```

`sed '/^>/ s/.*/>dat/' *.txt`

The output generates by sed is an concatenated file,
by adding loop, redirected output to a separate output files.

2. Is it possible to rename the **header names** with their respective **file names** ?

**Orginal file**

```
head -n 1 dat.txt
>xxxxxxxx ; zxf
```

**Modified file**

```
head -n 1 dat.txt
>dat
```

Suggestions please!

Comment: Yes, it is. But in your example, the filename is `dat.txt`, while the new header shows only _dat_, i.e. not the name of the file.

Comment: As for suggestions, I would use the `tail` command to produce a file with the header removed, and use the new header together with the output from `tail` to create the new file. An alternative would be to use `sed` to replace the first line of the file.

Comment: Able to do solve the question 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple using `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="dat.txt"   # Or maybe use Command-line parameter ${1}.

if [ ! -f ${filename} ]; then
  echo "'${filename}' is not a file."
  exit 1
elif [ ! -w ${filename} ]; then
  echo "'${filename}' is not writable."
  exit 1
fi

sed -i '1s/^.*$/> '${filename}'/' ${filename}
```

The `-i` option tells `sed` to update the file in-place.